# SQL removing duplicates but still keep the first

Tags: sql, duplicates, ssms, sql-delete

I need help with removing duplicate values but still keep the first.
Here's an example:

```
ID  Day Status
--------------    
111  1   X    
111  2   Y    
111  3   X    
111  4   Y    
111  5   Z    
222  1   X    
222  2   X
222  3   Y
333  1   Z
333  2   Z
333  3   Y
```

My output would be:

```
ID  Day Status
--------------
111  1   X
111  2   Y
111  5   Z
222  1   X
222  3   Y
333  1   Z
333  3   Y
```

Comment: Hint : `group by` and `min`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vamsi Prabhala help:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Day), Status
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ID, Status
```

Notice that: this answer is based on your data in `Day` column.